# Jquery .not class on $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I am quite new to Jquery, so sorry if this has already been answered.

I am doing this:

```
$(this).index();
```

In response to a click event. Now, as i understand $(this) refers to the context it is used in, and it will get the index of the element clicked. In my case, the markup is something like this:

```
<div class="real cloned"></div>
<div class="real cloned"></div>
<div class="real"></div>
<div class="real"></div>
```

Now, the problem is that i only want to register the ones named "real" and not "cloned". The issue is that if i click on the first "real", it will say it is index 2 (which is true, since the 2 cloned ones take 0, 1), but i really want it to be just 0, since it is the first with only "real" in the class.

I tried this:

```
$(this).not('.cloned').index();
```

But it does absolutely nothing. Still returns the same and counts the cloned with it. I thought it would only select the ones that didn't have "cloned" as a class, but here i was wrong :)

Hope someone can help me. Sorry for the long post.

Comment: You want to select all the `divs` which has `real` class but not `cloned` class, is it?

Comment: I don't know what do you need that index for, but that may be not the best solution. If you need to identify clicked div, consider using [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) along with [data- attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5). It may give you much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
$('.real:not(.cloned)').index(this);
// or
$('.real').not('.cloned').index(this);
//or
$(this).index('.real:not(.cloned)');
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Lovely! Great with 3 options. I am choosing this over 'Tony Barnes' due to the fact that i don't need a control structure :) will accept in 5 min.

Comment: Caution: All of these options could give false results. Say for example your markup was repeated, inside wrappers, and you wanted, as would seem appropriate under most circumstances, the clicked element's index amongst its own siblings. [See what these solutions give you here](http://jsfiddle.net/3jhtu2y3/1/)

Comment: Unless you really want to know the index of the clicked element amongst all `'.real:not(.cloned)'` elements on the entire page, then [here is a fix](http://jsfiddle.net/3jhtu2y3/2/) for the first two solutions. The third solution  is less amenable to a simple fix, though it may be possible.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Ya good point, really depending what result is expected

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('cloned')) {}
```